# nested array of object using map es6 doesn't work in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I don't see any error but a blank jsx using es6 map over a nested array of object.

https://codesandbox.io/s/9jpo8z0poy

my data

```
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Main Food",
    "categories": [
      {
        "name": "Sub Food",
        "nature_of_business": [
          {
            "name": "Wholesaler"
          },
          {
            "name": "Direct sales"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Jsx

```
<div>
  natural of business: {
    (data.categories || [])
      .map(o2 => o2.nature_of_business || [])
      .map(o3 => o3.name)
      .join(', ')
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mapping the data incorrectly. You have to get the first item of the array, not data.categories:

**Edit**: Re-written for easier ES6 reading.

```
 <div>
    natural of business: {
       data[0].categories.map(category => category.nature_of_business.map(cat => 
           <div>{cat.name}</div>
       ))
    }
 </div>
```

**Snippet of the mapping:**

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Main Food",
    "categories": [
      {
        "name": "Sub Food",
        "nature_of_business": [
          {
            "name": "Wholesaler"
          },
          {
            "name": "Direct sales"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

data[0].categories.map(category => category.nature_of_business.map(cat => console.log(cat.name)));
```

Comment: I want print the value in jsx

Comment: @SharonChai just add a <div> container for the cat.name that is returned from the last map and it should print your values in jsx :) like this `=> <div>{cat.name}</div>`

Comment: ouch I didn't realised I need to have map within map.